# How to remember to use return value?

Tags: c#

Sometimes I forget to use the return value when I **have** to. For example

```
var s = "foobar";
s.Replace("foo", "notfoo");
// correct: s = s.Replace("foo", "notfoo");
```

This also applies to my custom value-like classes, for example, where I use fluent x.WithSomething() methods that return new value object instead of modifying x.

One solution would be to use unit tests. However, this is not always applicable. So, how do I force a compiler - or, at least, runtime - error when returned value is not used?

Maybe, there's a ReSharper or VS solution?

UPDATE: OK it is not enforced by language. So null arguments are, but still I can throw exception if argument is null. And ReSharper can warn me about many things that are not enforced by C#. But I see no way to do the same for not-used return value - for those return values that I want to be used.

If not for system functions (like string.Replace), but at least for my own classes - is there any way? Like, returning RequiredReturn<T> or something like this.

UPDATE: what about AOP / PostSharp? If I mark return value or method with [UsageRequired], can I detect somehow using PostSharp that return value was used?

(note the C# tag)

Comment: If I'm not mistaking ReSharper creates a suggestion for unused return values. Not?

Comment: ah, good old scheme, where functions that modify variable have a name ending in '!'

Comment: I don't know. That's just a silly question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using FxCop (or Visual Studio Code Analysis, if you have it) for this?  It includes a rule that screens for use of return values from certain pre-defined categories of methods.  If your omissions aren't caught by the rule, you could create a custom rule that checks for them.  (The built-in rule would catch the String.Replace problem in your example.)

Comment: Hm, excellent! However, I switched "CA1806: Do not ignore method results" on for the project, and even set it to be error, but it doesn't fire anything even though I have ignored results.

Comment: Oops, from documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182273%28VS.100%29.aspx it works only for new(), string returns, and COM/P/Invoke. Not for my types - obviously because it can't decide if they're immutable.. However I can see how to add custom rules. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: The built-in rule doesn't check for all ignored return values, just for those that would commonly be considered problematic.  (Otherwise, there would be far too many false positives, and folks would disable the rule.)  Either your test cases don't meet the rule criteria, or there's a problem with your code analysis configuration.  To rule out the latter, could you please confirm whether a problem is detected for the String.Replace sample code from your original question?

Comment: Accepted because FxCop (and maybe Code Analysis) can be run from a build (as a tool) so it works not only from inside IDE.

Answer (score 3):

If it's really important that you deal with the output value, you could pass the function a value by reference and set that withing the function, rather than returning it.

That way the code calling the function is forced to consider the output value by having to supply it as a parameter at compile time

Comment: Agree, but then it's not about my question ;-) I'd really like to keep doing y = x.WithSomething().WithAnother();

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

It's the same question as asking how do I remember to assign something to my GetSomeStuff() method?

For instance, I keep doing:

```
GetSomeStuff();
```

But it should be:

```
Stuff some = GetSomeStuff();
```

Just remember. Simple.

On a related note, personally, <strike>I think the Replace method should not have been an instance method if it doesn't affect the instance (and yes, I'm aware that strings are immutable).</strike> the naming should better reflect we're dealing with an instance method on an immutable object.

**Edit:** To better reflect what I was trying to say, and work my comment into it as well.

Ah. Just noticed there is an option in [Resharper 4.5](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html) to discover 'Unused return values of non-private methods', that may exactly be what you want.

Comment: So immutable objects shouldn't have instance methods? I think this is a design pattern.

Comment: I know it's common, but it does cause the problems that the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: Also, it's about the naming of the method too. It would be far better if the instance method name was something along the lines of GetReplacedString. OK, not that verbose, but you get the idea.

Comment: Replace is a good example, because calling it without return value usage is meaningless; it has bad name that doesn't tell correct intent; so it would be very useful to know when its return value is not used. Well, in my functions I can go with GetWithSomething() instead of WithSomething()... but it's not 100% solution. "Just remember" doesn't work; I can "just remember" this one rule, but there're hundreds of them; that's why lint, ReSharper, and other tools were invented.

Comment: I can add my own meta-data with attributes. Yes I will have to remember... and yes I _WILL_ forget sometimes. I always try to automate things and remembering something that tool can check for me... Why do you insist on remember _this_ while taking other compiler errors/warning as granted? And yes, I always compile my C++ sources with warning level 4 and warnings as errors.

Comment: +1 for ReSharper 4.5 option. Of course I'd like non-tool solution better (i.e. AOP-related) but this will work to some extent.

Comment: Downvoted because there are ways to detect this sort of thing besides just "remembering".

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin for Visual Studio, [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). This plugin tells you on the fly when you are writing dumb code.

Comment: Even if I didn't mention ReSharper in the question (and I did), there're cases when one can't use it. For example, you can't afford it; or you can't use VS to edit sources; etc. There're levels of source checking: compile-time, run-time, tools checking... in order of preference, the latter being the easiest to miss the bug.

Answer (score 0):

There's no run-time solution.

<strike>There's an option on ReSharper's Inspection Severity page called "Method return value is never used". You could try turning this to "Show as Error".</strike>

**EDIT** Apparently not quite what's needed - it spots method's whose return value is *never* used anywhere. I should have realised that from the name!

Why not write your own tool? At the most basic level you could search your source for your method and report and error if it's not preceded by "=" (taking into account that the code might be split across multiple lines). At this level it's not interactive, but if it works you could convert it into a VS plugin.

Comment: It doesn't work for what I ask; it marks method's return value (in method declaration) if this return value is NEVER used in any place; i.e. it is redundant.

Comment: Even ignoring things like comments and multiline string literals it's not as simple. There are other ways to use the return value than assignment. Say `obj.Method( str.Replace("foo","bar"))`. 
Is the return value of Replace() used? Sure. Is there any equals sign? Nope.

Answer (score -1):

You really can't do that in any language following the C syntax - C, C++ or C#. The caller of the function is free to ignore the return value.

Comment: Not entirely true.  gcc allows you to add the warn_unused_result attribute on functions that causes a warning if the return value is ignored.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

Comment: Well, the caller is free, but while there are methods/functions where it makes sense, there are others where it doesn't. All side-effect free functions for example.
So while it would be inconvenient to get a warning for all such calls, it would definitely be helpful to be able to mark a method as "useless if the return value is ignored" and get a nice warning and a wavy underscore in the editor. In some cases I would even go as far as requiring the use of the return value and emitting an error.